# Using Javascript's typeof on DOM elements to check undefined (IE problem)

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs, undefined, typeof

I want to iterate over a list of DOM elements (check boxes) and keep going as long as this list defined.  The elements are 'c1r1', 'c1r2', 'c1r3', etc.  Once I hit an undefined one, I stop.  The problem seems to be using typeof with DOM elements.

Here's the offending code:

```
function domIsDefined(idString){
    alert(idString);
    var isItDefined = (typeof $(idString) != 'undefined');
    alert(isItDefined);
    return isItDefined;
}
...
for(i=1; domIsDefined('c1r' + i); i++){
    if($('c1r' + i).checked==true){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The crux of the problem is this line:

```
var isItDefined = (typeof $(idString) != 'undefined');
```

The problem, as I found out, is that typeof $(idString) always returns object, whether it is defined or not.  Is there any good way to do this sort of thing?  I guess I'll put in a try catch and check the .checked property early, but that feels disgusting.

Comment: is there any specific reason you can't get all the checboxes using single DOM method, i.e. getElementsByTagName('input') and iterate over the collection of nodes? Or, if you use jQuery, just `$(':checked').each( function(){ /*do stuff*/ });`

Comment: This is using prototype, sorry for the confusion.  I should have clarified that.

Comment: Also sorry about the IE in the title... I had thought it was IE only, but my Firebug console was just turned off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function domIsDefined(idString){
    return !!document.getElementById(idString);
}
```

Comment: Genius!  The problem here is that typeof loses information as it returns 'object' given "Any other objects" or null.  The boolean values of null and HTML objects are different though.  So the first ! casts to a bool, which is what I really needed.

Thanks!  This is beautiful!

Comment: Also, I like crazy solutions that use multiple operators in an unorthodox way.

Comment: I probably shouldn't be writing so many comments, but @jball showed that this works with prototype's $ as well.

Comment: I don't want to jeopardise my genius status but the !! thing is quite a common way to convert values into Booleans in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery always returns an object (an array). If the element with that ID is not found, then the length of the returned array will be 0.

```
var isItDefined = ($(idString).length > 0);
```

Update: for prototype, you should check for null to see if the object is found

```
var isItDefined = ($(idString) !== null);
```

Comment: I mean, I can check this myself.  Prototype does not always return an array (I'm pretty sure), so I tried casting it into an array.  This yielded no results though.

    var tempA = new Array();
    tempA[0] = idString;
    var isItDefined = ($(tempA).length > 0);

Comment: Oh alright, that works well.  For this instance I'd want a !, but this gets to the point of what I need.

Comment: @Josh - sorry, I was a little sloppy with the operator there - I've updated it to actually return `true` for `null` values :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the array. jQuery always returns a jquery instance, with an array of the matched elements.

```
$(idString).length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#id").length){}
```

Comment: I don't know if this means anything in jQuery, but it crashes prototype.

Answer (score 0):

$(), in jQuery, will always return an object.  Try this instead:

```
var isItDefined = (typeof document.getElementById(idString) != 'undefined');
```